# Installing ROS-Groovy Mobile on Raspbian

Tags: ros, raspberrypi, mobile, ros-groovy, raspbian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have been trying to install ROS Groovy Mobile on my RPi.  I keep getting an error when I run *sudo rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro groovy -y* which returns *ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
apt: command [sudo apt-get install -y python-rospkg] failed*

Any ideas how to get around this? I cannot install the package at all.  I commented out the dependency in roslib.

Anyone have an image of ROS Groovy Mobile or Full installed on Raspbian?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55703/installing-ros-groovy-mobile-on-raspbian/) by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2549 on 2013-02-19

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

good news, there is exactly what you ask for

[push this link hard!](http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Raspbian/Source)

Have fun with it :)

---

Originally posted by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) with karma: 1554 on 2013-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2013-02-20**:
That was the guide I was using.  I cannot get past 5.6 due to the error above.  Were you able to install it?

**Comment by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) on 2013-02-20**:
Yes and I also posted an image file on the very top of the tutorial ;)
There is a red box right under the command which tells you that this command will fail and how to fix it

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2013-02-20**:
Sorry I did not notice the link.  Thank you so much for that.  I edited many package.xml that contained python-rospkg but it still fails.  I will try the image now.  Thank you again.  I'd still like to be able to install from source but I'll try that in my spare time.

**Comment by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) on 2013-02-20**:
I added the robust option for rosdep (-r) which should give you a summary of all packages which have not been installed successfully at the end. If there is no ERROR and only some apt-get commands which were not found, you will be fine and can go on with the tutorial. Feel free to edit it as well

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2013-02-21**:
Thank you.  I just tried the image and it works perfectly.  I will try to compile it from source another time.   Your help with much appreciated.

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2013-02-23**:
@kalectro Do you use the RPi as the master or another laptop?  I configured my laptop as the masters for my RPi.  I can see the rostopic list but I cannot echo any topics.  When I try to use a simple command to publish such as rostopic pub /test std_msgs/Int32 300, I can see it locally on the PRi.

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2013-02-23**:
Any ideas?  (Sorry I ran out of characters)

**Comment by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) on 2013-02-23**:
It will also work with a master running somewhere else. The issue you have might be due to your DNS. Try setting ROS_IP, that should work

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2013-02-24**:
I set the ROS_IP in the .bashrc but it still does not work.  I can see the topic but cannot echo it.  Do I need to run any commands after I write the image to the SD to initialize ROS?

**Comment by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) on 2013-02-24**:
no, ROS should work out of the box. Did you set ROS_IP on the raspberry pi and the laptop? I would not recommend setting it in the bashrc file because the address could change. Just to be clear... set ROS_IP to the IP of the respective device. Find it out using ifconfig

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2013-02-25**:
I set the ROS_IP correctly and I confirmed by echo $ROS_IP. I set it in the bashrc since all my interfaces are static for now. The communication is there between the two but the RPi can publish or echo topics but I can see the topics even new ones created on the master laptop.

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2013-02-25**:
Do you use the GUI on this image?  I cannot get the USB devices to work once I boot the GUI using startx but once I use a original image they work fine.

**Comment by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) on 2013-02-25**:
no, I did not try any gui on the Raspi

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2013-02-27**:
@kalectro I saw your post on the Raspi forum and thought maybe something could be corrupt with the image I downloaded.  Do you mind posting the md5sum for the image?  By the way, did you compile all the ROS stuff for the Raspi yourself?

**Comment by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) on 2013-02-28**:
I do not have the original image on my computer anymore, sorry. What you could try is downloading my previously uploaded image from here http://goo.gl/0yoT8
And yes, I compiled everything from source using a chroot environment. I wrote everything down in the wiki

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2013-02-28**:
Thanks Kalectro, it worked.  I just needed to at my master as a host in /etc/hosts with that last image.  Thanks for doing all the work of compiling everything and posting the image.  In addition, thank you for all your help.